# deselect text from particular tag

Tags: javascript, selection

Is there a way to deselect text from particular tag.For example.

```
<p id ="first">first text</p>
<p id ="second">Second text</p>
```

If the select text from both the tags but i want to deselect the tag with the first id.I know you can deselect all the selected text using

```
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

but is there a way to deselect text with a particular id?

Comment: Okay so you want something like Some <p id ="first">first text</p> Text , Then you only want user to return 'Some Text' Have I got you correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with CSS, You can specify below CSS properties to allow selection on specific elements at all.
Here based on your requirements you can achieve this in two ways.

**1) CSS**
 - In this approach if you provide any element with following CSS then it won't be included in selection and when you get selection using below code it will not return the text of the #first element

**HTML Code:**

```
var selObj = window.getSelection(); 
var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
selObj.toString();
```

**CSS Code:**

```
#first {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

**2) Javascript**
 - This is concept approach and you need to try it out with proper syntax, you can write a function that uses selection object and traverse through HTML tree and checks each elements for whatever your condition is, and gets it's texts and appends it in your selection string, How you can traverse through DOM is your choice

```
var selection = '';//your selection string
var selObj = window.getSelection(); 
var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
var nextElem;

// Get start of the 
selection += selObj.startContainer.getText().substr(selObj.startOffset);    
nextElem = selObj.startContainer;
while(true) {

  nextElem = nextElem.nextElem; // Get this somehow
  selection += nextElemr.getText();
  if(condition) {
     break;
  }
}
```

So basically using four variables of selection object you can do this, and they are, startContainer, startOffset, endContainer, endOffset

Comment: actually i want to deselect text based on what user selects at runtime

Comment: @soldiershin Okay so you want something like Some <p id ="first">first text</p> Text , Then you only want user to return 'Some Text'


Have I got you correct?

Comment: @ParagBhayani for example if i have two p tags <p id ="first">first text</p> <p id ="second">second</p> and user selects first text and second text i want to deselect the first text

Comment: @soldiershin: Okay let me try, will let you know

Comment: @soldiershin: There are two ways 1 is using CSS which I have mentioned above, which is working fine and another is concept which you need to try with javascript, I can give you idea and you can try it out, I am updating the answer to contain both